# How to correctly post data with ajax into div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Script:**

```
function buttonBuild(id, building, nick)
  {
      $("#BuildedBox").ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "BlockEditor/build.php",
       data: 'block_id=' + id + '&building=' + building + '&nick=' + nick,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
         $.load("#BuildedBox")
       }
     });
 }
```

**build.php:**

```
include_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/db.php");

$block_id = $_GET['block'];
$building = $_GET['building'];
$nick = $_GET['nick'];

echo"$block_id - $building - $nick";
```

**index.php:**

```
<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"buttonBuild(k152, digger, Name);\" >[BUILD]</a> 
<div id="BuildedBox"></div>
```

seems my script wont work. what i have done wrong?

Comment: What is this `$("#BuildedBox").ajax({` and `$.load("#BuildedBox")`? what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I am trying to post data from link to a DIV.. in real time..

Answer (score 2):

check this out

```
function buttonBuild(id, building, nick)
  {
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "BlockEditor/build.php",
       data: 'block_id=' + id + '&building=' + building + '&nick=' + nick,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
         /***************/
         $("#BuildedBox").html(response);
         /***************/
       }
     });
 }
```

Comment: ohh didn't see that...corrected now...just corrected what OP posted :D

Answer (score 1):

```
   var weightd = $("#weight").val();
              var user_id = 43;
                $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                url:"<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/ajax/insert.php",
                data: { weight:weightd,user_ids:user_id},
                success:function(result){
                  $("#result1").html(result);

                });


<div id="result1">Result div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$.load("#BuildedBox")` to `$("#BulderBox").html(response)`.

When you ask the script for data via ajax, the data provided gets into the "response" variable. As you want to write this data into the div, you must use the ".html" method.

Easier using "load" in this way:

```
function buttonBuild(id, building, nick)
  {
      $("#BuildedBox").load("BlockEditor/build.php?block_id=" + id + "&building=" + building + "&nick=" + nick);
 }
```

The "load" method loads data from the server and writes the result html into the element: https://api.jquery.com/load/

**EDIT:**

As @a-wolff says in the comment, to use POST in load, you should construct like this:

```
function buttonBuild(id, building, nick)
  {
      $("#BuildedBox").load("BlockEditor/build.php",{
        block_id:id,
        building:building,
        nick:nick
      });
 }
```

Comment: you could pass data as object to load() method to use POST and avoid caching issue